# how to add properties to array of objects in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of objects as follows:

```
var array = [{'content1': 'abc', 'id1':'100'},{'content2': 'xyz', id2':'200'}...];
```

Now I want to add new elements(I don't know if I can, **but not manually**) to each of these objects and I want the same array to be as follows:

```
var array = [{'content1': 'abc', 'id1':'100', 'name': 'foo'},{'content2': 'xyz', 'id2':'200', 'name': 'bar'}...];
```

Can someone please help me to do this?

Comment: How about iterating through this array ?

Comment: Have you tried looping over the array and assigning a value to the `name` property on each element? In Javascript, it's ok if the element doesn't have a `name` property to begin with, it will happily let you add one.

Comment: what is source for name property values? Not really clear where the problem lies

Comment: Consider to update the question to ask for the specific error and do not use the responses to post updates.

Answer (score 2):

You can use angular merge

```
   var array = [{
    'content1': 'abc',
    'id1': '100'
  }, {
    'content2': 'xyz',
    'id2': '200'
  }];

  var array2 = [{
     'name': 'foo'
  }, {
     'name': 'bar'
  }];

  var object = angular.merge({}, array, array2)
```

and the result will be all properties merged:

```
var array2 = [{
    'content1': 'abc',
    'id1': '100',
    'name': 'foo'
  }, {
    'content2': 'xyz',
    'id2': '200',
    'name': 'bar'
  }];
```

Take a look at this plunker:

http://plnkr.co/edit/X7Zv99qNXSkmHh4lIBMP

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `push` to set property. `push` can use to add array element.
If you want to use

`$scope.object.array1.push(value);`

then value should be an object like

`var value = {content1: 'xyz',id:'4'};`

To add property you can follow bellow process.

Say your object like:

```
$scope.object={
     array1: [{content1: 'abc', id1:'100'},
       {content2: 'xyz', id2:'200'}],
     array2: [{content1: 'abc', id1:'100'},
     {content2: 'xyz', id2:'200'}]
    };
```

and if you want to add property `name` for each object of array1. you can use `forEach` to add new property and value. say called a function `addProperty`  to add property and value.

```
$scope.addProperty = function(){
  var i =0;
  angular.forEach($scope.object.array1, function(eachObj) {
    i+=1;
    eachObj.name ='foo'+i;
  });
};
```

then out put of array1 will be

```
[{"content1":"abc","id1":"100","name":"foo1"},{"content2":"xyz","id2":"200","name":"foo2"}]
```

[PLUNKER DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/SLTLCABu4TZ6Z6u2wWBc?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way it is using .map();

```
array.map(function(element) {
    return element.name = insertedName;
});
```

You can use a function which will send **insertedName**.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to skin this.  Just depends how dynamic you need it to be.

Here is a basic example showing how it can be done by accessing your objects by index:

```
var array = [{'content1': 'abc', 'id1':'100'},{'content2': 'xyz', 'id2':'200'}];

array[0].name = 'foo';
array[1].name = 'bar';
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0f6L1x44/

If you need to add names more dynamically, you could do something like:

```
findById(100).name = 'foo';
findById(200).name = 'bar';

function findById(id) {
    var index = array.map(function(item) { return item.id; }).indexOf(id);

    return array[index];
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/pj31n0Lj/

Note: I cleaned up your array objects in this example.  Not sure why you have content1 and content2, etc.

Comment: if I have an object like $scope.object={array1: [ ], array2:[ ] }; how can I push new values into those arrays? when I try $scope.object.array1.push(value); I get an error saying cannot read push. Please help.

Comment: Again, depends how dynamic it needs to be.  You could just do $scope.object.array1[0].name = 'foo'.

Answer (score 0):

I have an object like:

```
$scope.object={array1: [ ], array2:[ ] };
```

How can I push new values into those arrays?

When I try `$scope.object.array1.push(value);` i get an error saying: *cannot read push.*